# WiX Burn 3.7 MsiNTSuitePersonal showing wrong value for Windows 7 Home Basic

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, burn

I am using Burn to get my prerequisites installed. One of the prerequisites requires me to check if the current OS is the [Home Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Main_editions) edition of Windows 7. I tried checking it with MsiNTSuitePersonal as follows.

```
<ExePackage Id="someId"
            Cache="no"
            Compressed="no"
            PerMachine="yes"
            Permanent="yes"
            Vital="yes"
            InstallCommand="/q"
            SourceFile="Redist\some.exe"
            DisplayName="Display something"
            InstallCondition="(MsiNTSuitePersonal = 1)"/>
```

Following is the log from WiX Burn Setup.

> [093C:02E0][2013-04-01T17:14:21]i052: Condition '(MsiNTSuitePersonal =
>   1)' evaluates to false.

The above condition is for Wix 3.7 Burn. It always gives me the result false on Windows 7 Home Basic, while using the same thing in an MSI it works perfectly. See the following log.

> Property(S): MsiSystemRebootPending = 1 Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00
>   Property(S): VersionNT = 601 Property(S): WindowsBuild = 7600
>   Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 0 Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor =
>   0 Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 1 Property(S): MsiNTSuitePersonal =
>   1

Also, I tried checking the same condition using the registry, but how do I compare a string in InstallCondition?

I would like to do something as follows.

```
<ExePackage Id="UWSOptionfor7Home"
            Cache="no"
            Compressed="no"
            PerMachine="yes"
            Permanent="yes"
            Vital="yes"
            InstallCommand="/q"
            SourceFile="Redist\UltiDev\UltiDev Web Server Setup.exe"
            DisplayName="UltiDev Web Server"
            InstallCondition="(IsWin7PersonalEdition = 'Terminal Server Personal')">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are referring to `MsiNTSuitePersonal` which is the *Windows Installer* built-in property. The variable in Burn you are looking for is `NTSuitePersonal` (note: it's not prefixed with `Msi`, because it's not provided by the Windows Installer).

For the complete list, see *[Burn Built-in Variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html)*.

Comment: That's going to be fun to keep straight. (e.g. recent SecureCustomProperties discussion)   I see people confuse MSBuild properties with Preprocessor Properties with MSI properties and now Burn properties.  Would be really good material to cover in developer training.

Comment: Thanks Rob! but issue still remains there I used burn variable NTSuitePersonal